# Time comparison in Advantage SQL

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

Trying to do a time comparison in an advantage query.  Haven't been able to find the answer in the Advantage documentation.  Seems like it should be very simple.

Table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL ( 
      ID AutoInc,
      Date Date,
      [T] Time
)
```

Based on [this book on google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=vvh8DjXFaBEC&pg=PA319&lpg=PA319&dq=advantage%20database%20timestamp%20comparison&source=bl&ots=R2N6tnxHMp&sig=gGBadlLl9jBnyllX4Fw5wSb7sKI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7pDwVMzoFompNpfugagK&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=advantage%20database%20timestamp%20comparison&f=false) I figured I should be able to just do a comparison against a literal expressed like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE [T] > '9:00:00 AM'
```

But that throws

```
Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = S0000;   NativeError = 2124;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Invalid operand for operator: > [Invalid TIME] -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 27
```

Comment: Did you try uisng `cast()` (`cast(blah as time)`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use the TIME'HH:MM:SS' (24h) or TIME'HH:MM:SS am' (12h) literal format:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE [T] > TIME'09:00:00 am'
```

I think you get the 2124 error, because you are using either upper case am/pm notation or because you did not use a leading zero.

See also:

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage11/master_sql_literals.htm

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation under SQL Literals (in the ADS help file, under the *Advantage Developer's Guide, Part II - Advantage SQL, Chapter 11 - Introduction to Advantage SQL, SQL Literals*)

> Time literals are enclosed in single quotation marks, and use one of the following four formats: HH:MM, HH:MM AM (or PM), HH:MM:SS, or HH:MM:SS AM (or PM). If the AM (or PM) is missing from the literal, 24-hour time is assumed. The AM/PM part of time literals is not case sensitive. The following are valid time literals:
>
> '19:10'
> '4:43 AM'
> '9:00:45 pm'
> '22:19:59'

Using this table definition and data:

```
create table #temp (ID AutoInc,
                    Dt Date,
                    Tm Time);

insert into #temp (Dt, Tm) values (CurDate() - 1, CurTime());
-- Wait to make sure time changes slightly
insert into #temp (Dt, Tm) values (CurDate(), CurTime());

select * from #temp;

/* Output:
    ID   Dt           Tm        
    --   ----------   -----------
    1    02/26/2015   11:50:22 AM 
    2    02/27/2015   11:51:02 AM
*/
```

The following query successfully retrieves the proper row based on the time correctly (adjust, of course, to the appropriate times for your data):

```
select * from #temp where Tm = '11:50:22 AM'
```

Tested using ARC32 against Advantage 10.10 with the native ADT table type.